# How to use the values of one column to access values in another column?

Tags: pandas

How to use the values of one column to access values in another

```
import numpy
impot pandas

numpy.random.seed(123)
df = pandas.DataFrame((numpy.random.normal(0, 1, 10)), columns=[['Value']])
df['bleh'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: numpy.random.randint(0, x + 1, 1)[0])
```

so how to access the value 'bleh' for each row?

```
df.Value.iloc[df['bleh']]
```

## Edit:

Thanks to @ScottBoston. My DF constructor had one layer of `[]` too much.
The correct answer is:

```
numpy.random.seed(123)
df = pandas.DataFrame((numpy.random.normal(0, 1, 10)), columns=['Value'])
df['bleh'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: numpy.random.randint(0, x + 1, 1)[0])
df['idx_int'] = range(df.shape[0])
df['haa']     = df['idx_int']  - df.bleh.values
df['newcol']  = df.Value.iloc[df['haa'].values].values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['Value'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[-1.0856306033005612,
 0.9973454465835858,
 0.28297849805199204,
 -1.506294713918092,
 -0.5786002519685364,
 1.651436537097151,
 -2.426679243393074,
 -0.42891262885617726,
 1.265936258705534,
 -0.8667404022651017]
```

Your dataframe constructor still needs to be fixed.

---

Are you looking for:

```
df.set_index('bleh')
```

output:

```
         Value
bleh          
0    -1.085631
1     0.997345
2     0.282978
1    -1.506295
4    -0.578600
0     1.651437
0    -2.426679
4    -0.428913
1     1.265936
7    -0.866740
```

If so you, your dataframe constructor has as extra set of [] in it.

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame((np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)), columns=['Value'])
df['bleh'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0, x + 1, 1)[0])
```

`columns` paramater in dataframe takes a list not a list of list.

Comment: Neither (sorry for the confusing question): I want a `Series` whose first entry is `[df.Value.iloc[df['bleh'].iloc[s].values] for s in range(df.shape[0])]` but with just the numeric values (not the column names).

Comment: Neither (sorry for the confusing question): I want a column with entries  `[df.Value.iloc[s].values[0][0] for s in df['bleh'].values]` but with just the numeric values (not the column names).